# Is there something I need to do to allow alternate logic syntax in php on IIS

Tags: php, iis

I am encountering a strange problem getting a PHP script to work on IIS.  In my script I've used the alternative logic syntax:

```
<?php
     if ($a == 5):
         echo "a equals 5";
         echo "...";
     elseif ($a == 6):
         echo "a equals 6";
         echo "!!!";
     else:
         echo "a is neither 5 nor 6";
         endif;
?>
```

Now I'm finding this is causing a "500 Server Error" message until I change the syntax to:

```
   if($a==5){
         echo "a equals 5";
    }
```

Is there something I have to do on IIS to turn on this alternate syntax for if/elseif/else.

Comment: Do you, possibly, have a space between `else` and `if` in your actual code? There can't be a space when using that syntax. (I know it's not there in what you posted, but quite frequently what people post is not what they're running)

Comment: This is definitely not the actual code. It's the example [from the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).

Comment: Yes, this is just an illustration I didn't want to post my actual code - it does use this syntax and no extra spaces!

Comment: post the _actual_ code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

500 Server Error is usually triggered when you are on production environment in IIS and it triggers with ANY error.

In this case I tested your code in development mode and it told me "Undefined variable: a"

I set `$a = 6;` and your code works perfectly. I'm on IIS7/PHP 5.4.13

If you want to see the errors you can:

- On IIS manager > your pool > PHP Management you can change the environment to development.
- Change the php.ini and set the error_reporting as desired, and display_errors to On.
- on Runtime: add this to the beginning of your script: `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and `ini_set('display_errors', 'On')`

Comment: Could you please tell me how I can turn off production mode and get PHP errors printing to screen?

Comment: Yes. See the edit on my answer!

Comment: Great thanks - I'd forgotten an endif; line somewhere.  With the errors switched on it is possible to debug now!